# How to set LeftBarButton at the place of BackButton in ios

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, back-button, uinavigationitem

I have set LeftBarButton in the NavigationItem is below way.

**Code :**

```
UIButton leftBtn = new UIButton();
leftBtn.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 14, 30, 30);
leftBtn.SetImage(UIImage.FromBundle("cancel_white_icon"), UIControlState.Normal);
leftBtn.TintColor = GargiColor.WhiteColor();

UIBarButtonItem barBtnLeft = new UIBarButtonItem();
barBtnLeft.CustomView = leftBtn;
barBtnLeft.TintColor = GargiColor.WhiteColor();
NavigationItem.SetLeftBarButtonItem(barBtnLeft, true);
```

**Output :** 
[image]

**EDIT :**

After adding **@SushiHangover** code the Output is below[image]

**What I am Expected :**

The Cancel Button have more space in the Left Side. How to set it to LeftSide as the backbutton.

**My Require Output is below :**

[image]

@SushiHangover final output :[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var negativeSpace = new UIBarButtonItem (UIBarButtonSystemItem.FixedSpace);
negativeSpacae.Width = -8;

var leftBtn = new UIButton (new RectangleF (0, 0, 25, 25));
leftBtn.SetImage(UIImage.FromBundle("cancel_white_icon"), UIControlState.Normal);
leftBtn.TintColor = GargiColor.WhiteColor();

UIBarButtonItem [] bArray = {
    negativeSpace, new UIBarButtonItem (leftBtn)
};
NavigationItem.SetLeftBarButtonItems (bArray, true);
```

Comment: `(negetive)` is not taking in count i already done it before.

Comment: This is working fine in my project. I've tested. Are you sure it is `UIBarButtonSystemItem.FixedSpace` that you added?

Comment: where you define `backButton` ??

Comment: it can not display the `Cancel` button even. i also add this code `button.ImageView.Image = UIImage.FromBundle("cancel_white_icon");` but the image is not display.

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: I'm sure that is working in your project, but using my crash reports as evidence, pushing a uiview with negative width or using negative insets within a NC can (and will cause crashes) depending upon the device/version.